# Obtain attribute value from a specific field

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a point shapefile with a high number of attribute fields. For a single point, there is only 1 of these attribute fields completed, the others have a "NULL" value for that point. The field name for which a value is available is furthermore defined in the field "Blockname".

So, for point 1, the value in the field "Blockname" is OVSTNP_180. In the field "OVSTNP_180" (and only in this field), there is a value listed (e.g. 741).

In order to label the points, I would like to create a field "label" where this value (741 in the example above) is calculated. Which expression do I need to use (in ArcGIS)?

I assumed that, for example in ArcGIS, I could state something like this:
Label= ["[Blockname]"]
but that does not work...

Comment: Which of QGIS or ArcGIS Desktop do you wish to ask about in this question. By asking about both you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Comment: This is a complex calculation using a field value to define the field to copy from, I would think this would require some python (arcpy). It might be possible to do with QGIS but I can't think of a way to do this with pyqgis. Can you edit your question with a screen shot of your table and pick a platform that you're truly interested in... if you have both ArcGis and QGIS that's fine but I think this would be one of those things that's easier in arcpy.

Comment: I limited the question to ArcGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Since all other fields are `<Null>`, the following works, although it probably won't be very performant if you have lots of points and fields. I'd suggest using the same logic in field calculator to populate your `label` field.

Note, I'm not using `field` at all.
[image]

```py
def FindLabel ( [a] , [b] , [c] ):
  return max([a] , [b] , [c])
```

If say, the other fields weren't all empty, the following would work to populate your `label` field properly based on the value in `field`.

```py
fc = '/path/to/fc'
fields = ['a', 'b', 'c']
source = 'field'
label = 'label'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [source] + fields + [label]) as uCursor:
    for row in uCursor:
        row = list(row)
        i = fields.index(row[0]) + 1   # adding 1 since source is first
        row[-1] = row[i]
        uCursor.updateRow(row)
```